# Change button onclick after first click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm having some struggles getting this to work.
I have a button, and I want it to execute Javascript function A, and in that function A, i want to change the Onclick to function B. Thus getting as result when the user taps the button a SECOND time, it's executing B. With the

```
<Button onclick="A();">Click me</button>
<script>
Function A() {
document.getElementById("button").onclick=B();
}
Function B() {
Alert("hello world");
}
```

In function A(), it doesn't execute FIRST A and after that B, it instantly executes B. Could anyone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: The buttons has onclick='A()', i'm editting the code. Sorry if this was Unclear :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a function name with the parenthesis, like `B()`, that invokes the function immediately. Instead, you'll want to set `onclick` to be just the name of the function, `A` or `B`.

Your overall solution could look something like this:

```
function A(event) {
  // Function logic...
  event.target.onclick = B;
}

function B() {
  // Function logic...
}

document.getElementById("button").onclick = A;
```

Comment: Well this fixed the issue, and it's explained pretty well. Thank you man :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling B with `B()`.

Use `document.getElementById("button").onclick=B;`. Note that there's no parentheses after `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to change any attribute of a button onclick.  Below, I update the `onclick` attribute to instead execute function `B()`

```js
function A() {
  $('#toggler').attr('onclick', 'B()');
}

function B() {
  console.log('Updated to B()!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggler" onclick="A()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `id` instead of the `onclick` for the `button` then target it from `javascript` like this:

```js
function b()
{
   console.log('I am in B.')
}

function a()
{
  console.log('I am inside A.');

  button1.removeEventListener('click', a);
  button1.addEventListener('click', b);
}

var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');  // get the button element

button1.addEventListener('click',a); // assigns a click listener to a() at the beginning
```

```html
<Button id="button1">Click me</button>
```